# Opening a image file

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am having trouble figuring out the VBA syntax to open a file for MAC OS

Here is my code

```
Sub OpenFile()
    Open (Users/dongougkim/ShareSync/Dan's stuff/Current Services/logo.png)
End Sub
```

I have also tried

```
Open ("Users/dongougkim/ShareSync/Dan's stuff/Current Services/logo.png")
Open ("Macintosh HD/Users/dongougkim/ShareSync/Dan's stuff/Current Services/logo.png")
Open ("Macintosh HD:Users:dongougkim:ShareSync:Dan's stuff:Current Services:logo.png")
```

Please help. Driving me crazay

Comment: Try ~/Users/... or /Volumes/Macintosh HD/...

Comment: The path `"Macintosh HD:Users:dongougkim:ShareSync:Dan's stuff:Current Services:logo.png"` is correct but I am not familiar with `Open()` syntax in MAC to open image files.. I know `Open "testfile.txt" For Output As 1` works in MAC?

Comment: Spongessuck & Siddharth, I tried both of your syntax, and it didn't work.

Edit: Yes, maybe Open doesn't work with image file... What else should I try?

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix `Users` with a slash, otherwise the path is relative.

Try this:-

```
Sub OpenFile()
    Open (/Users/dongougkim/ShareSync/Dan's stuff/Current Services/logo.png)
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the image file once you have it open? It is important to know as you may require a different statement altogether and the Open syntax is incomplete. If you can give me more information I can revise my answer.

Comment: Simply see (and check) the image. New to VBA (on mac btw), so not sure about a better way to debug.

Comment: There are several ways to "open" a file, each with different features and outcomes.  You have to be more specific. Are you simply checking if the file exists or are you trying to read the contents of the image?

Comment: I'm trying to see the picture itself in a little window. Make sure I got the right image and all.

Comment: Then you should be using an `Image` control and assign the file path to the `Picture` property.  This will display the image.  The method you are using to open the file is used for read/writing manually.